# Dynamic height of a div

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

well, i'm trying to do a like/unlike script. A bar have to show the % of likes in green.

Here my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // like and unlike click
    $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){
       // do some tratement

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'likeunlike.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {postid:postid,type:type,userid:userid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var likes = data['likes'];
                var unlikes = data['unlikes'];
                var ratio = (parseInt(unlikes) / (parseInt(unlikes) + parseInt(likes))) *100;

                $("#likes_"+postid).text(likes);        // setting likes
                $("#unlikes_"+postid).text(unlikes);    // setting unlikes
                $("#likeBarprcent_"+postid).css({"height":ratio+'%'}); // 
                if(type == 1){
                    $("#like_"+postid).css("color","#ffa449");
                    $("#unlike_"+postid).css("color","lightseagreen");
                }

                if(type == 0){
                    $("#unlike_"+postid).css("color","#ffa449");
                    $("#like_"+postid).css("color","lightseagreen");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here my html code

```
<div class="likeBar" id="likeBar_<?php echo $postid; ?>">
    <div id="likebarprcent_<?php echo $postid; ?>"><?php echo $ratio ?></div>
</div>
```

When users clicks on like or dislike, it automatically updates my counter (like, dislike) without refresh the whole page. 
What i wanna do, it to update the height of my likebarpcent div automatically.

Exemple: When the user is on my index page, the height's bar is at 66 % (2 likes, 1 dislike). If the user clicks on dislike (so 2 likes, 2 dislikes), the height's bar is, now, at 50%.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console when you test the event?

Comment: It can't be _automatic_ but this line should already be doing it `$("#likeBarprcent_"+postid).css({"height":ratio+'%'});`, it may just be that you aren't selecting the element correctly, it seems to be `#likebarprcent_xx`. If not that, what's the problem, exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: $('#likeBarprcent') has a capital letter in it, whereas your HTML ID 'likebarprcent_XXX' does not. Try changing the typo.